# ASP.NET Core 3.1 web application use authorization for multiple areas using different authentication types

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, asp.net-core-mvc, authorization

I have an ASP.NET Core 3.1 application which follows domain driven architecture and it has 2 areas, one for admin and other one for customers (application users).

I want to enable authentication and authorization for each area separately. For example use Identity 4 for the customer area and cookie base authentication for admin area. But it should be done using a single database and role base authentication should not used to separate areas.

What is the best approach to follow. For example "Multiple authentication scheme", Or any other method.

Comment: Maybe you can use [role-based](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/roles?view=aspnetcore-3.1) authorization.

Comment: @mj1313 thank you for your reply, Yes for each area it has own roles but the requirement is to use 2 different login with different databases

Comment: @Nayanajith You can use a Multitatent Application system for the solution which you want.for that reason,admin and customer will have a separate database. both people will not access other data.

Comment: @BrettLee thank you for your response. It's not possible to use 2 databases as the requirement is to use a single database and use separate login , register for each area

Comment: Is it possible to use Cookie Authentication and Identity authentication both in a single project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it comes to login for admin and customer you can implement it by using `acr_values` ([see definition in spec](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#AuthRequest)). Identity server can decide how to authenticate based on `acr_values`, for example if you provided `admin_login` as `acr_values`, then based on that Identity Server will authenticate user (use different identity provider or different database/table).

Your application needs to know whether user wants to login as customer or admin before you redirect to identity server authorize endpoint. In order to know that you will have to implement different authentication schemes in your application (one for admin and one for customer). Once you know user login type, you can add correct `acr_values`. Below code is not tested but it should give you an idea on how to implement it.

```
        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultScheme = "CustomerCookie";
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
        })
        .AddCookie("CustomerCookie", options =>
        {
            options.Cookie.Name = "CustomerCookie";
            options.ForwardChallenge = "oidc";
        })
        .AddCookie("AdminCookie", options =>
        {
            options.Cookie.Name = "AdminCookie";
            options.ForwardChallenge = "admin-oidc";
        })
        .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
        {
            // Configure all other options needed.

            options.SignInScheme = "CustomerCookie";
            options.CallbackPath = "/signin-oidc-customer";

            options.Events.OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = (context) =>
            {
                context.ProtocolMessage.SetParameter("acr_values", "customer_login");

                return Task.FromResult(0);
            };
        })
        .AddOpenIdConnect("admin-oidc", options =>
        {
            // Configure all other options needed.

            options.SignInScheme = "AdminCookie";
            options.CallbackPath = "/signin-oidc-admin";

            options.Events.OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = (context) =>
            {
                context.ProtocolMessage.SetParameter("acr_values", "admin_login");
                return Task.FromResult(0);
            };
        });
```

On identity server side you have full control on what to do based on `acr_values`, you can use external provider for admin.

You could use [IIdentityServerInteractionService.GetAuthorizationContextAsync](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/interactionservice.html) to retrieve `acr_values` and you could implement [IProfileService](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/reference/profileservice.html) so that once authenticated, you can decide what claims to include based on user type (admin or customer).

That would be the basic idea, hopefully it is useful.

Comment: Thank you for the detail answer and this is useful